# Calculate $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ of $f(x)=kx^2$, and the limit of the sums

Tags: real-analysis

$f : [0, 1] → R$,

$P_n = \{t_0, · · · , t_n\}$

$f(x) = kx^2$

Calculate the upper and lower sums,
and show that their limits are equal to $k/3$.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I was able to find the upper and lower sum, but I'm stuck on calculating the limits

Comment: What did you get for the upper and lower sums? That would help a lot to know what you are stuck on.

Comment: You can find formatting instructions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I'll edit your question and you can click edit to see what I did.

Comment: Thanks for editing! I am still getting used to the plataform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the partition $P_n = \{t_0 = 0, ..., t_n = 1\}$, each interval runs from $t_i$ to $t_{i+1}$, and for an increasing function like $f(x) = kx^2$, the minimum value will be at the left edge, and the maximum at the right edge, giving us $k(t_{i})^2$ and $k(t_{i+1})^2$ for min and max values.  So $$L(f, P) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} k(t_{i})^2\cdot (t_{i+1} - t_i)$$ while $$U(f, P) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} k(t_{i})^2\cdot (t_{i+1} - t_i)$$
Hopefully those match what you calculated.

Now $\lim_{|P| \to 0} L(f,P) $ looks like a mess to calculate for a general partition.  I'll work the easier case of evenly spaced points in the partition.  In that case, $t_i =\frac{i}{n}$ and we find $$L(f,P) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} k(\frac{i}{n})^2 \cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{k}{n^3} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^2 = \frac{k}{n^3}\frac{(n-1)(n-1+1)(2(n-1)+1)}{6}$$
or $$\frac{k}{n^3}\frac{(n-1)(n)(2n-1)}{6} = k\big[\frac{2n^3}{6} - \frac{3n^2}{n^3} + \frac{n}{n^3}\big]$$ and the limit as $n \to \infty$ is $\frac{k}{3}$.  Likewise for the upper limit.

Comment: Note that it suffices to find some sequence of partitions $P_n$ such that $L(f, P_n) , U(f, P_n) \to I$ as $n \to \infty$ to show that $f$ is integrable and $I = \int kx^2 \, dx$. Since $\inf U(f,P) = \sup L(f,P) = \int kx^2 \, dx$ = k/3, we are done.

Comment: Life saver, thanks!